# How to install NetCDF plugin to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, extensions

From the GeoServer manual:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html

To add a NetCDF data store the user must go to Stores –> Add New Store –> NetCDF.

In my install (Windows, version 2.16, Tomcat), I do not see the NetCDF entry, but only those options:

```
Raster Data Sources
 ArcGrid - ARC/INFO ASCII GRID Coverage Format
 GeoPackage (mosaic) - GeoPackage mosaic plugin
 GeoTIFF - Tagged Image File Format with Geographic information
 ImageMosaic - Image mosaicking plugin
 WorldImage - A raster file accompanied by a spatial data file
```

I do not see the way to install the plugin anywhere, and this post [Installing netCDF plugin for Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179394/installing-netcdf-plugin-for-geoserver)
The link at "Geosolutions IT Training." which may have the plugin installation instruction, is broken.

I also tried installing NetCDF-4 native library https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/netcdf-out/nc4.html#nc4 on windows, and it did not help.

There must be some very basics missing here. I do not see the extension/plugin present on my 2.16 GeoServer install, and surprisingly, google around and I do not find anywhere on how to install the plugin.

Comment: did you install the netcdf extension? http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.16.0/extensions/geoserver-2.16.0-netcdf-plugin.zip

Comment: Thanks Ian. I did not and that's the "basics" I missed. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the way to install an extension in GeoServer, is written in Spanish: https://www.cursosgis.com/como-instalar-una-extension-en-geoserver-el-servicio-wps/

Answer (score 0):

1. First download the extension from [here](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.20.x/ext-latest/geoserver-2.20-SNAPSHOT-netcdf-plugin.zip)
2. Navigate to the directory where you installed geoserver if you are using Linux probably here

```
    /usr/share/geoserver/
```

3. Inside the installation directory follow the path below

```
    /webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/
```

4. unzip the extensions files inside the lib folder, so that the .jar files are directly in the lib folder
5. restart geoserver and you will find the upload